# Powershell sort piped to get-content & sort takes over machine

Tags: sorting, powershell, memory-management, cpu-usage

I copied and pasted a little too fast, and ran the code below.  It basically froze the entire server for 15-20 minutes.  My input file is an 8 MB xml file with about 50,000 lines of text.

```
get-content $latestFile.FullName  | sort | get-content $latestFile.FullName  | sort | out-file -FilePath $latestFile.FullName.Replace(".xml","_Sorted.xml") -Encoding ASCII  
get-content $latestFile2.FullName | sort | get-content $latestFile2.FullName | sort | out-file -FilePath $latestFile2.FullName.Replace(".xml","_Sorted.xml") -Encoding ASCII
```

So what exactly is the above doing?  How or why does Powershell allow you to pipe anything to a get-content or a string?  Is it "multiplying the rows together, similar to a SQL Cartesian product? 
And why would it take over the CPU and memory?  It even froze up remote desktop to the server, the entire GUI locked up so that you could use task manager to see what was going on?  What wouldn't Windows just process it slower instead of dedicating all its resources to this stupid and accidental typo?

This was what I intended to do, and runs in about 30 seconds.

```
get-content $latestFile.FullName  | sort | out-file -FilePath $latestFile.FullName.Replace(".xml","_Sorted.xml") -Encoding ASCII  
get-content $latestFile2.FullName | sort | out-file -FilePath $latestFile2.FullName.Replace(".xml","_Sorted.xml") -Encoding ASCII
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few questions in here, I'm gonna try and answer the ones relating to "What is PowerShell doing?"

I ran a simple test, with an 8 line file.  I ran the following

```
gc .\MyFile.txt | sort | gc .\MyFile.txt
```

And the result was the contents of MyFile.txt being echo'd 8 times (ie 8x8=64 lines output).  So, if you have 50,000 lines in your text file, you're then sorting 2,500,000,000 lines and write them to a file.  Seems like an operation which may take a lot of CPU time and memory.

Looking at the documentation for [Get-Content on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx), we see that it accepts a few values from the pipeline ByPropertyName.  I used the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117947/when-a-commandlet-accepts-pipeline-input-what-is-the-difference-between-byprope) to try and figure out which parameter is being piped.  I ran

```
gc .\MyFile.txt | sort | gm
```

And saw that it has a ReadCount property (well, each element of the returned array does...).  This suggests, to me, that the pipe to the second Get-Content is taking the ReadCount from each element.  The documentation says

> This parameter does not change the content displayed, but it does affect the time it takes to display the content. As the value of ReadCount increases, the time it takes to return the first line increases, but the total time for the operation decreases. This can make a perceptible difference in very large items.

So if the ReadCount of each element in the array being returned by sort is large, combined with the above arithmetic, I think this could take quite a while, and lock your remote connection for a bit.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!  Just seems like Windows wouldn't let one task take the whole computer.  I saw memory spike in PerfMon logs.